# Trigger the javascript function of the anchor's href during document.ready

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to trigger the javascript function of an anchor tag during page load?

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jansian/yCvBH/)

```
<a  id="WebTree" href="javascript:alert('testing')">click me</a>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#WebTree').trigger('click');
    //$('#WebTree').click();
    // after the page load I'm expecting to see the alert but it's not working
});
```

I'm expecting to see an alert after the page is loaded but I'm not

**EDIT**

Ok here's simple explanation why I'm asking this question.

Here is the original link which was dynamically generated by sharepoint.

```
<A id=ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl01_WebTreeViewn1 href="javascript:TreeView_PopulateNode(ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl01_WebTreeView_Data,1,ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl01_WebTreeViewn1,ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl01_WebTreeViewt1,ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl01_WebTreeViewt1i,' ','TaxonomyMetadata','Pages\\TaxonomyMetadata','t','30:FieldNameNode:e305128c-217b-47b4-81b9-db0c1e59f98f:3b529925-3610-485a-9133-bc958f7ab28e:dbf365da-565b-41ca-966d-f9bf29d9b2cf:30|ListNode|e305128c-217b-47b4-81b9-db0c1e59f98f|3b529925-3610-485a-9133-bc958f7ab28e|ea06a686-46c5-4470-a1ab-4fe4341589c8','tt')">

    <IMG style="BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px" alt="Expand TaxonomyMetadata" src="/_layouts/images/MDNCollapsed.png">
</A>
```

Bottom line I have no control of the anchor tag.

Comment: you are just passing the alert inside the click event... sorry it's not actually what I wanted

Comment: That's why it's a comment and not an answer =D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
$(document).ready() {
    var code = $('#WebTree').attr('href');
    eval(code);
}
```

Comment: Dammit, was just about to come in and post something similar but included setting the `onClick` by `$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#WebTree').click(function() { eval($('#WebTree').attr('href')) });
    $('#WebTree').click();
});`

Answer (score 3):

You should use `onclick` attribute instead of `href`. Triggering click on an element programmatically doesn't activate the `href` attribute.

```
<a id="WebTree" onClick='javascript:alert("testing")' href='#'>click me</a>
```

If you want to change the location of the page you can use `location.href`.

```
$('#webTree').click(function(){
   location.href = this.href
}).click()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qnN2d/

Comment: More precisely, _"using `.trigger('click')` will not trigger the native `click` event"_.

Comment: There is a reason why I'm asking that kind of question. The link is created dynamically by sharepoint and all I can do is just to trigger the javascript of the href.

Comment: @CarlsJr. So the best way is using `location.href`

Answer (score 1):

so you cant [try this way](http://jsfiddle.net/yCvBH/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#WebTree').trigger('click');
    $('#WebTree').click(function() {
    alert(1);
    });
    // after the page load I'm expecting to see the alert but it's not working
});

 $(window).load(function () {
        $('#WebTree').click();
 });​
```

Answer (score 1):

Move event binding to javascript:

```
<a  id="WebTree" href="#">click me</a>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#WebTree').click(function(){
        alert("testing");
    });
    $('#WebTree').trigger('click');
});
```

[Source](http://jsfiddle.net/yCvBH/3/)

[See Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)